# How to fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, arrays, jfilechooser

I am getting an error when trying to use a JFileChooser to scan a text file add it to an array and parse one of the strings to a double and two to integers. Does it have to do with the fact that the addEmployee method adds the six parameters to an arrayList? Here is the code...

```
else if (e.getSource()==readButton){
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("src");
        if  (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            empFile=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
            Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");
            while(scan.hasNext()){
                String[] rowData = scan.next().split(":");
                if(rowData.length == 5){
                    rowData[4] = null;
                    fName = rowData[0];
                    lName = rowData[1];
                    position2 = rowData[2];
                    firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
                    secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
                    empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]);
                }
                else{
                fName = rowData[0];
                lName = rowData[1];
                position2 = rowData[2];
                firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
                secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
                empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]);
                }
                if (position2.equals("Manager")){
                    c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, 0, empNum);
                }
                else if(position2.equals("Sales")){
                    c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, 0, empNum);
                }
                else{
                    c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, secondParam, empNum);
                }
            }

        }
```

> John:Smith:Manufacturing:6.75:120:444
>
> Betty:White:Manager:1200.00:111
>
> Stan:Slimy:Sales:10000.00:332
>
> Betty:Boop:Design:12.50:50:244

Comment: post the stacktrace/error here

Comment: also the the inside of the file you are parsing

Comment: Sorry ,what is the stacktrace/error? And I'm not parsing a file just the [3],[4], and [5] of the array.

Comment: the error the java gave you copy paste it here so we can examine it

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at GUI$aListener.actionPerformed(GUI.java:329)                here is what the error is and line 329 is lName = rowData[1];

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]);

row data only having size 5 that means index 0-4, Thats why ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is getting

So Initialize String[] rowData = new String[6];

Comment: So I have edited the code to how it looks above but I am getting the same error may it have to do with how the textFile is?

Comment: you have to initialize the rowData as String[] rowData = new String[6]

Comment: Ok so I added the text for the textfile in my post above. Your answer seems right but didn't do the trick.

Comment: I did that and it didn't do it.

Comment: Now also you are getting the same exception. Can you post the exception string

Comment: @JojoJohn `rowData = new String[6]` won't do any good if it's followed by `rowData = scan.next().split(':');`.

Comment: Same exception look at ajb's answer below I think we have found what is wrong but need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[] rowData = new String[5]; // edited out of original post
  rowData = scan.next().split(":");
```

The first statement allocates an array of 5 `Strings` and sets them all to `null`.  The second statement just throws away the array you just allocated.  The result of `split` will return an array of however many items it finds, and then you assign `rowData`, which is a *reference* to an array, to a reference to the new array.  The old one gets garbage collected.  So there's no guarantee that `rowData` will have 5 elements after this assignment.

You'll have to decide what you want to do if the `split` doesn't return enough array elements.  You could use something like `Arrays.copyOf` that could put the `split` result into some of the `rowData` elements while leaving the rest alone, but then the unassigned elements will still be `null`, and you'll just get a `NullPointerException` a few lines later.  So you have some design decisions to make here.

**More:** You may want to consider using the `Scanner` method `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.  `next()` will return just one token, which means it will stop at a space character, which means you will have problems if someone is named "Mary Beth" or something like that.

Comment: Oh actually I see what your saying how can I make it that it puts a null when there is nothing.

Comment: How do your `if`, `if else`, and `else` check for the wrong number of fields?  Anyway, you look at `rowData[5]` **before** your `if`.  If there is some position that won't have as many fields, you would need to make sure you don't try to access a nonexistent field until **after** you check the position.

Comment: Ok so I have edited the code as you can see above but I am getting the same error on the lName = rowData[1]; of the else statement. How can I make the code so it reads in the code and checks for the length.

Comment: @user3530205 I don't know why you're getting the error; perhaps you need to print `rowData.length` and see what it is, and maybe also print the string you're splitting (by saving `scan.next()` in a variable).  You already know how to check `rowData.length`.  But if it's 0 or 1, you need to figure out why, and if it's an error in your input file, you probably should do a "sanity check" before doing anything else (`if (rowData.length < 5) then` print an error message `else {` do the rest of your logic `}`, or something.